# How to write Solver "Set Cell" / "to Value of " / " by Changing Cells" in VBA for Variable Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm a beginner in Excel VBA , All I want to ask about is How to write the Cells Notation in Excel VBA in Solver Piece of Code

This 's what Recording a macro Produced

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$3", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$F$2", Engine:=1 _
    , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$3", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$F$2", Engine:=1 _
    , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$2", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
```

I Want Cell "F2" , "F3" to be Dynamic (because it's always variable due to a Loop Process)

F3 to be [Cells(3, 6 + ((j - 1) * 8))]

F2 to be [Cells(2, 6 + ((j - 1) * 8))]

where "j"  is a Counter that ranges from 1 to (a predefined value)

I know about Range.Address(1,1) but when I tried it → Solver didn't solve

I hope anyone helps me with representing Cells Dynamically in Solver in VBA

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens when you try `...SetCell:=Cells(3, 6+((j-1)*8)), ..`?

Comment: It doesn't solve or even gives an Error

Answer (score 0):

The SetCell parameter needs the address of the cell as a string:

SetCell:=Cells(3, 6+((j-1)*8)).Address

If it doesn't solve, step through the code (using the Debug Menu/Toolbar > Step Into command) and make sure the correct input is being passed into the solver.

Use the View menu to show the Immediate window if not already visible, and as you step through the code, use the ? command to print out values of variables and expressions:

?Cells(3, 6+((j-1)*8)).Address